# Is there a way to add an IronPython reference to an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, python-2.7, asp.net-mvc-5, ironpython

I'm trying to run some Python scripts on my ASP.NET MVC web project, recently I heard about [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). It can really help me since I have my core web application functionality (user management, security, ...) written in ASP.NET MVC framework now I want to run some recommendation, search algorithms and I/O stuff in Python (because of the range of available Python sources and also open source libraries plus the fast development techniques) and use it in my ASP.NET MVC web app.

I found a [link](http://www.codevoyeur.com/Articles/Tags/ironpython.aspx), but It was no help for me!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can add to the `IronPython` package using the NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. The standard library is distributed separately in the `IronPython.StdLib` package.

Comment: Thanks but i think it's for using .Net assemblies in IronPython, I want to use python to write some algorithms in my ASP.NET MVC app, if you know it please show this with an example